# Gitstats error means I don't get git stats

Tags: git

I've been trying to get a nice report from gitstats but I just get errors. Can anyone help?

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have  the `gitstats` folder in the `PYTHON_PATH`.
Try to call it with `python git-stats`.

You can call specifying the repo path and output path:

```
python git-stats C:\Users\my_git_repo\ C:\Users\my_git_repo_stats
```

Comment: I did exactly this, but used 'gitstats' instead of 'git-stats'. The latter gives a message of 'python: can't open file 'git'stats': [Errno 2] No such file or directory' whereas the former gives the original bunch of stuff  in my OP.

Answer (score -1):

OK got it.

It works beautifully on OSX - I set it up in minutes - so I can't help help thinking that Windows 8 is the problem here.

Solution: use OSX not Windows 8.